# Vue 2 Laravel 5.3 Eloquent unable to retrieve data from object

Tags: eloquent, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

Vue2 has been reading eloquent pretty well so far for me but except this point where I struggle to debug.

**Shop-show.vue**

```
<template>
.....
.....
    <div class="row">
      {{shop.user.id}}
    </div>
.....
.....
</template>

<script>
  export default{
    mounted(){
        this.getShop()
    },
    methods:{
        getShop(){
            var vm = this
        vm.$http.get('/getShop/'+vm.shopId).then((response)=>{
            vm.shop = response.data.data.shop
        })
    },
.....
.....
 }
</script>
```

**ShopController.php**

```
.....
.....
    public function getShop($id)
    {
      $shop = Shop::where('id',$id)->with('user')->firstOrFail();
      $response = [
          'data' => [
              'shop' => $shop
          ]
      ];
      return response()->json($response);
    }
.....
.....
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/getShop/{id}', 'ShopController@getShop');
```

here when I render `{{shop.user}}` in my template it gives me perfectly fine object of user including info such as `id` and `name`, however when I do `{{shop.user.id}}` or `{{shop.user.name}}` it console log errors as followings

**error#1**

> [Vue warn]: Error when rendering component  at
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/soyegg/resources/assets/js/components/Shop/Shop-show.vue:

**error#2**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at Proxy.render (eval at  (app.js:335), :46:47)
>       at VueComponent.Vue._render (eval at  (app.js:444), :3096:22)
>       at VueComponent.eval (eval at  (app.js:444), :2464:21)
>       at Watcher.get (eval at  (app.js:444), :1663:27)
>       at new Watcher (eval at  (app.js:444), :1655:12)
>       at VueComponent.Vue._mount (eval at  (app.js:444), :2463:19)
>       at VueComponent.Vue$3.$mount (eval at  (app.js:444), :6104:15)
>       at VueComponent.Vue$3.$mount (eval at  (app.js:444), :8494:16)
>       at init (eval at  (app.js:444), :2777:11)
>       at createComponent (eval at  (app.js:444), :4120:9)

this has never happened before, very weird. Please help.

Comment: `shop` is defined in [data](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data) of vue instance?

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: Saurabh did solve this problem, but this question is still open to anyone who can contribute a better and more proper answer. Look forward to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are loading `vm.shop` from `getShop` method, which is an async method, you will not have anything in  `vm.shop` till it is populated, so initially you will get this error.

To prevent this error, you can put a null check before using it, with the help of [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if), like following:

```
<template>
.....
.....
    <div class="row" v-if="shop && shop.user">
      {{shop.user.id}}
    </div>
.....
.....
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Saurabh. but that seems not explaining why i `{{shop.user}}` does consists of object but `{{shop.user.id}}` gives error. I just tried `v-if` as you said but the same error happens.

Comment: sorry. I just refine as your said and it works now. But this seems troublesome every single time i needa do v-if for this simple task. What should I do better to improve my code?